# Bounding a $C^k$ function on the unit disk

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

In my reading there is the following "simple" claim:

> If $u \in C^k(\overline{\mathbb{D}})$ and if all derivatives of $u$ up to order $k$ vanish on $\partial \mathbb{D}$, then for some $C>0$ it holds that $|u(z)| \leq C (1-|z|)^k$ on $\mathbb{D}$.

Any insights or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Try Taylor expansion based at a boundary point. The error can be uniformly controlled.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be right if $u$ is a nonzero constant function ...

Comment: @Henning Makholm, by "all derivatives" I mean to include the zeroth derivative

Comment: In that case the zeroth derivative will not vanish in $\partial \mathbb{D}$

Comment: Anyway, wouldn't "$|u(z)| \leq C (1-|z|)^k$ on $\mathbb{D}$" imply that $u$ is identically zero on $\mathbb D$, by Cauchy's integral formula applied to a circle with arbitrary small $1-|z|$?

Comment: @Henning Makholm, if $u$ were holomorphic (or even harmonic), then yes, otherwise not necessarily

Comment: @wellfedgremlin: Um, then I might be misunderstanding $\mathcal C^k$ here.

Comment: @Raff Thanks Raff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less a proof.

Take $z\in \mathbb{D}$. Write it as $z=(x,y) = (rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta))$ with $0\leq r<1$.

Now define $g_\theta:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  by $g_\theta(\rho) = u(\rho cos(\theta),\rho sin(\theta))$.

I guess that $g_\theta$ is in $C^k([0,1])$ and, using Taylor around $\rho = 1$, there exists $r_\theta$ in $(0,1)$ such that $$ g_\theta(r) = g_\theta(1) + g_\theta ^{(1)}(1) (r-1)+ \frac{g_\theta ^{(2)}(1)}{2!}(r-1)^2 + \dots + \frac{g_\theta ^{(k-1)}(1)}{(k-1)!}(r-1)^{(k-1)} + \frac{g_\theta ^{(k)}(r_\theta)}{k!}(r-1)^k$$

Using that $r = |z|$ and the hypothesis that the derivatives vanish at the boundary:

$$ u(z)=u(rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta))=g_\theta(r) = \frac{g_\theta ^{(k)}(r_\theta)}{k!}(r-1)^k = \frac{g_\theta ^{(k)}(r_\theta)}{k!}(|z|-1)^k$$

Taking absolute value yields:

$$ |u(z)| = \left| \frac{g_\theta ^{(k)}(r_\theta)}{k!}\right| (1-|z|)^k \leq \frac{M}{k!} (1-|z|)^k $$

where $M$ is a uniform bound in $\theta$ for the the $k$-th derivative of $g_\theta$ in $[0,1]$, that exists because of the continuity of the derivatives of $u$ up to order $k$ on the compact set $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Comment: In your proof you can take $g_\theta : [0,+\infty[ \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and every thing work

Comment: I don't see why should I allow $g_\theta$ to take values in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: but $u$ take values in $\mathbb{C}$ not in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: LOL I'll fix it.

Comment: This looks good. Is there a result you have in mind for allowing to use Lagrange remainder theorem and Taylor expansion on a boundary point?     There is a result that says if $u \in C^k (\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ then there exists $u^{\prime} \in C^k (\mathbb{U}$ where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ s.t. $u^{\prime}$ agrees with $u$ on $\mathbb{D}$

Comment: Not really, but I think that the standard proof for Lagrange in several variables should work.

Comment: Another, annoying, possibility would be to take $\epsilon > 0$ and consider Taylor around $\rho = 1 - \delta$ choosig $\delta$ such that it makes all the lower terms of order $\epsilon$. Then take $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.